# image responsive width without media queries

Tags: javascript, resize, responsive-design, media-queries

I have been trying to do the same thing ex.fm does in their website.
You may want to check out the [trending](http://ex.fm/trending) section in ex.fm. The tiles
are neatly divided in the right part of the site.

When you resize your window the sizes of the divs containing the image 
automatically resizes too. It does not use media queries since the style is applied
directly to the element. Check out the Elements tab in the developer tools then
try resizing the main window.

Do you have any idea how they calculate the size to be applied?

Heres the selector to help you find the element in the screenshot

`#right > #song_list > #trending_song_list > .trending_song`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got something working:

```
<head>  
<style>
body {  
        overflow-y: hidden; 
}       
.song { 
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        outline: 1px solid black;
        float: left;
}       
#container {
        width: 100%;
}       
</style>
<script>
updateWidths = function() {
        var container = document.getElementById("container");
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("song");
        var rect = container.getBoundingClientRect();
        var container_width = rect.width;
        var elements_that_fit = Math.floor(container_width / 128);
        var new_size_px = container_width / elements_that_fit;
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                elements[i].style.width = new_size_px + "px";
                elements[i].style.height = new_size_px + "px";
        }
}
window.addEventListener("resize", updateWidths);
window.addEventListener("load", updateWidths);
</script>
</head>
<body>  
<div id="container">
<script>
for (var i = 0; i < 512; i++) document.write('<div class="song">Hi</div>');
</script>
</div>  
</body>
```